# Why isn't C array initialization syntax allowed for arbitrary assignments?

Tags: c, arrays

I was trying to learn the array fundamentals in Java and this question arises:

Version 1:

```java
int[] x  = {12,34,56,78};
```

Version 2:

```java
int[] x;  
x = {12,34,56,78};
```

Version 1 is correct but version 2 is incorrect.

Why is this the case? What is the story behind it?
Please, describe this from a **compiler-oriented** point of view.

Comment: Neither version is correct. Perhaps you meant `int x[] = {12, 34, 56, 78};`. `int [] x` is a syntax error.

Comment: It would be more interesting to ask why `int x[4]; x = {12, 34, 56, 78};` is not allowed, since a number of answers are addressing the uninteresting fact that the type is incomplete at declaration (due to the unknown array size) and not whether there is a grammatical or semantic reason not to allow the latter assignment.

Comment: The reason is that it is disallowed by the language specification. `{...}` is an initializer-list. An initializer-list is allowed during initialization (6.7.8). There is no corresponding clause for assignment-expression (6.5.16) that allows an initializer-list. In other words, it's disallowed because there is no rule that allows it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: If you are responding to my comment, then the question is whether there is some problem in modifying the C grammar or semantics to allow this, not whether the C standard says it is this way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Responding to original question, which struck me as rather strange. "I just made up some syntax out of thin air. Why doesn't it work?"

Comment: Is this question about Java or C? You tagged it as C, but in the text you state that you are learning Java. Did you use the wrong tag or did you want a comparison between the two languages? Would you mind clarifying it?

Answer (score 3):

#### The compiler needs to know how much storage to allocate for the array when it is declared.

```c
int x[] = {12,34,56,78};
```

In this case the compiler knows that it needs storage for four integers; this is comparable to saying `int x[4]`.

```c
int x[];
/* ... */
x = {12,34,56,78};
```

However, in this case the compiler sees `int x[]` and knows it must allocate space for an array but it doesn't know *how much* until it gets to the following line, at which time it is too late.

Answer (score 2):

In the latter case, the first line the compiler needs to handle is just `int x[];`. The compiler does not know how long to make the array unless you either give it a length `int x[4];` or give it the initial values, allowing it to determine the length.

Comment: Exactly. At the time you declare the array, you allocate the memory to contain the number of elements. With no information about the dimension or without listing the actual elements, the compiler does not know how large the array must be.

Answer (score 2):

Here is why

This is variable declaration and initialization using array initialization syntax:

```
int[] x = {12,34,56,78}; // this is java. my bad
int x[] = {12,34,56,78}; // this is c
```

This is variable declaraction:

```
int[] x; // java again
int x[]; // this is c
```

You are only permitted to initialize a variable (which includes using the array initialization syntax) when you declare the variable.

This is variable assignment with a syntax error:

```
x = {12,34,56,78};
```

Comment: Does your compiler accept `int[] x = {12,34,56,78};`? Have you tried it? Which compiler and version is it?

Answer (score 1):

What looks like an assignment here is actually *initialization*. Such syntax can be used only as part of a declaration, but not in a stand-alone expression.

The two parts of this syntax (to the left and to the right of the `=` sign) work together: compiler derives the size of the array `int x[]` from the number of items in the initializer; it cannot be added to the type of `x` at a later point, i.e. when the assignment is made, because the size of a C array must be known at the point of declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Simple...the Version 2 does not know how to allocate space for the array values